# Incorrect "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header while using AWS CloudFront & ApiGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an application which has the following architecture,

CloudFront -> API gateway (proxy-integration) -> http (service on eks cluster),

As, the api gateway is using proxy-integration, the required CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is being returned from the service running on eks cluster.

When I am triggering the request using api gateway url then I am able to see the correct value for the (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header. however, when I am using the CloudFront URL then the value of the (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header is changing to "*". I do not have any Response headers policy set on CloudFront.

Can you help me identify which other setting of CloudFront may impact the header value?